# Array Diffing: Compare large arrays with item movement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to find differences between States in React. But also movements inside the state should be detected. For example, if I deleted the first item:

```
{"state":[
  {"x": 1, "y": 3},
  {"x": 4, "y": 5},
  {"x": 2, "y": 6},
  {"x": 0, "y": 9}
 ]
}

{"state":[
  {"x": 4, "y": 5},
  {"x": 2, "y": 6},
  {"x": 0, "y": 9}
 ]
}
```

I use the jsondiffpatch package, but it works only when the last Item is deleted. but for diff(state, state1) I get this:

```
{
  "state": {
    "0": {
      "x": [
        1,
        4
      ],
      "y": [
        3,
        5
      ]
    },
    "1": {
      "x": [
        4,
        2
      ],
      "y": [
        5,
        6
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "x": [
        2,
        0
      ],
      "y": [
        6,
        9
      ]
    },
    "_t": "a",
    "_3": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 9
      },
      0,
      0
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want to check if an item was just moved also. So the Difference should be:

```
{
  "state": {
    "0": [
      {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 3
      },
      0,
      0
    ]
  }
}
```

I use the diff and patch from jsondiffpatch for an undo function and the undo state.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to get the difference or we can say the intersection of two arrays.
You can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersection) or [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#intersection) to get your desired output.
Both of them has a variety of util functions available.

Comment: Thank you, this looks good. But I use the diff and patch from jsondiffpatch for an undoState for my Undo Function. Do you think Lodash works for this, too?

Comment: Ohh Alright.  Unfortunately, these libraries does not provide such a util function right now.